# Find common elements in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` having the same columns. I would like to find the elements within a column that are in common.
For example

**df1**:

```
Col1 Col2 Nam1 Nam2 Net
AD    AS   AS   ADS AB
BF    SA   WQ   AFW AF
RW    KJ   IQ   QIE LK
```

**df2**:

```
Col1 Col2 Nam1 Nam2 Net
RW    WQ   HF   HGJ AB
BF    AS   DD   VCC LJ
RW    KJ   IQ   ADS JH
DS    QW   LJ   NB  LK
```

I would like to have the following (on Net)

```
Col1 Col2 Nam1 Nam2 Net
AD    AS   AS   ADS AB
RW    WQ   HF   HGJ AB
RW    KJ   IQ   QIE LK
DS    QW   LJ   NB  LK
```

I have tried as follows:

```
df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Net', how='inner')
```

but it duplicates all the columns' name (_x and _y) and also it seems not extracting only the elements in common.

Comment: Can you please explain the output?

Comment: The output is made by all the Net value in common within the two dataframe. If a Net value is in both the dataframe, I take both information on it from the two dataframes df1 and df2

Comment: @LucaDiMauro do you have duplicates in the column Net in the same dataframe, like in df1 could you have twice AF for example?

Comment: @Ben.T, yes, I have some duplicates on Net in the same dataframe. I got the elements in common using Venn's diagrams to have a visual output. Now I would like to get the same information using join

Comment: If I understand correctly, each column in the result contains all the items which appear in both dataframes. Is there any meaning to the rows in the output? Does it matter that AD (col1) and AS (col2) are in the same row?

Comment: @Roy2012, I would need only t consider elements in both dataframes looking at Net. If they are in both the dataframes, I would like to add them into a new dataframe; otherwise I can skip them. The values in Col1, Col2, Nam1, Nam2 may be the same and have some values, but for building the dataframe (expected output) I would not need to focus on them. The steps should be: select unique Net from all the dataframes, so I should have a list of Net values that I need for the expected output. Then, for each dataframe, select all the rows which contain a Net in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you just want those rows which share the same net value? You can start with,

```
vals =  set(df1['Net']).intersection(df2['Net']) 
print (vals)
# {'AB', 'LK'}
```

Now, filter out those values and concatenate:

```
pd.concat([
    df1.query('Net in @vals'),   
    df2.query('Net in @vals')], ignore_index=True)

  Col1 Col2 Nam1 Nam2 Net
0   AD   AS   AS  ADS  AB
1   RW   KJ   IQ  QIE  LK
2   RW   WQ   HF  HGJ  AB
3   DS   QW   LJ   NB  LK
```

Comment: Thank you so much cs95. So set(df1['Net']).intersection(df2['Net']) could be used also for the Venn's diagrams, could it not? One question: why should I not consider a join?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro yes, idea there is to get the intersection of elements, so there are many ways to skin the cat, so to speak. As for why you don't want to use a join -- you technically could: join (df1, df2 on='Net'), then take the "net" column values and use that to filter the original. IMO this is better in terms of performance (since in join we discard most of the joined result except from a single column). But it's up to you.

Comment: thank you so much. It was just for better understanding the approach to the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

One explicit way to do it would be:

1. Obtain set of common items

```
common_items = set(df1['Net']) & set(df2['Net'])
```

2. Get relevant rows from dataframes

```
df1_common = df1[df1['Net'].isin(common_items)]

Col1 Col2 Nam1 Nam2 Net
AD    AS   AS   ADS AB
RW    KJ   IQ   QIE LK
```

```
df2_common = df2[df2['Net'].isin(common_items)] 

Col1 Col2 Nam1 Nam2 Net
RW    WQ   HF   HGJ AB
DS    QW   LJ   NB  LK
```

3. Concatenate the two dataframes

```
pd.concat([df1_common, df2_common])
    
Col1 Col2 Nam1 Nam2 Net
AD    AS   AS   ADS AB
RW    WQ   HF   HGJ AB
RW    KJ   IQ   QIE LK
DS    QW   LJ   NB  LK
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less my answer with slightly different variations for step 1 and step 2.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is very similar and you were slightly faster.